# MySQL - Retrieving the record with the maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table like below on my MySQL database:

```
employee
-------------------------
id    name    num
1     Jack    1
2     John    1
3     Jack    2
4     Steve   1
5     Jack    3
6     Steve   2
7     Carol   1
```

The thing I want to do is to retrieve names with the highest "num" value.

For example:

```
5     Jack    3
```

There more than one records named Jack but I want to get the one with the maximum "num" value.

I've tried to use the query below:

```
SELECT MAX(num),id,name FROM `employee`
```

But it returns the *id and name of first record* (first "Jack") but the num of the latest.

```
MAX(num)    id     num
-----------------------
3           1      Jack
```

Of course I can try to use "Order by" but I also want to retrieve the **only** record with the highest value.

```
SELECT num,id,name FROM `employee` order by num desc
```

This query will also return all the records including the smaller ones.

```
id    name    num
-------------------------
3     5       Jack
2     3       Jack
2     6       Steve
1     1       Jack
1     2       John
1     4       Steve
1     7       Carol
```

When I try to group by name, it returns the records grouped by name but again only the small records.

The both of the queries below give the same result:

```
SELECT num,id,name FROM `employee` group by name order by num desc 


SELECT * FROM
(
select * from `employee` order by num desc
) as employee_tmp
group by name
order by num desc
```

Again, it groups with only the first and smallest records.

```
id  name    num
1   Jack    1
2   John    1
4   Steve   1
7   Carol   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `LIMIT 1` clause to your query like

```
SELECT num,id,name FROM `employee` order by num desc LIMIT 1
```

**Edit**:
OK, I misunderstood your original question. The following lists each name with the highest `num` value:

```
SELECT a.* FROM employee a 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT name na, MAX(num) nu FROM employee 
  GROUP BY name ) b ON na=name AND nu=num
```

See here for a demo: http://rextester.com/MOL28087

Comment: what about the other records? I want all of them with the highest values. Like "Jack with num 3", "Steve with num 2"

Comment: @amone, please check again, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use inner query with `MAX`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee
WHERE num = (
    SELECT MAX(num) FROM employee
);
```

This would give you the required result.

Comment: It returns the only one record. I want all of them with the highest values. Like "Jack with num 3", "Steve with num 2"

Comment: Highest value here is `3`. So, it will return all the records with value `3`. Please note that `2` is not the highest value so corresponding records will not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

MAX(`column_name`) will return max of all records,

```
SELECT emp.* FROM `employee` emp INNER JOIN
(SELECT name,MAX(num) as num FROM `employee` GROUP BY name) tbl
ON emp.`name` = tbl.`name` AND emp.`num` = tbl.`num`
```

We have used inner query to find out the name and max num of that name and then joined with the main table on name col and num col.
We need to mention group by so that it gives the name and max of each num for that name

I think, this should solve your purpose